# Menú de opciones a barra de navegación

Tags: html, asp

[image: Resultado]tengo un menú de opciones pero ahora quiero mostrarlo cómo barra de navegación, ¿hay alguna opción?
Adjunto código con elemento select, saludos.

```
    <select name="Tip" onchange="submit()"style="border-radius: 8px; cursor: pointer`; width:220px;">
    <%
    strQuery = "SELECT distinct(Tipo) FROM Lineas order by Tipo limit 5" 
    Set RsMarca = conn.Execute(strQuery) 
    Do Until RsMarca.EOF
    Tipo=RsMarca("Tipo")
    if Tip=RsMarca("Tipo") then
    selec="selected='selected'"
    else
    selec=""
    end if
    if Tipo="1" then
    Tipos="AUTO / CAMIONETA"
    end if
    if Tipo="2" then
    Tipos="CAMION"
    end if
    %>
    <option <%=selec%> value="<%=RsMarca("Tipo")%>"><%=Tipos%></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Eso es ASP clásico?

Comment: Es correcto, asp

Comment: Uhh esto es como el griego antiguo. Y tu quieres convertir ese select en otra cosa?? puedes poner un ejemplo del resultado final?? Además me parece que te falta el final del código un `end` y un `</select>`

Comment: Así es, buscaba la opción de mostrarlo en un <nav> o algo similar, para que en lugar de presentar la lista de opciones sólo tengan el enlace directo. Añadí la foto de la salida

Comment: Hola Lizbeth, bienvenida a [es.so]. Deberías [edit] y mostrar el código que has probado, como ejemplo de lo que estás explicando. Te invito a realizar el [tour] y que visites [ask] para aprender a realizar un [example]. Recibirás más respuestas, y de calidad, si la pregunta está correctamente redactada.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que algo como esto estas buscando, agregue algunas clases tipo bootstrap que es lo más frecuente.

Tienes que agregar un enlace correcto en los atributo `href`

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
    <%
    strQuery = "SELECT distinct(Tipo) FROM Lineas order by Tipo limit 5" 
    Set RsMarca = conn.Execute(strQuery) 
    Do Until RsMarca.EOF
      Tipo=RsMarca("Tipo")
      if Tip=RsMarca("Tipo") then
        selec="active"
      else
        selec=""
      end if

      if Tipo="1" then
       Tipos="AUTO / CAMIONETA"
      end if

      if Tipo="2" then
        Tipos="CAMION"
      end if
    
    %>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link <%=selec%>" href="algo/<%=RsMarca("Tipo")%>"> 
         <%=Tipos%>
      </a>
   </li>
 <%'y el cierre del loop????%>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Si, justo, muchísimas gracias, me sirvió bastante

Comment: @LizbethCarranco Que bueno, recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así te parece